# recovery_behaviors move_base turtlebot amcl

Tags: navigation, move-base, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how do you specify the recovery_behaviors for general amcl navigation? I included the following code in a file called `move_base.launch.xml` but it didn't spin when it found it didn't know where it was.

```
<param name="recovery_behaviors" value="[ {name: rotate_recovery, type: rotate_recovery/RotateRecovery}, {name: conservative_reset, type: clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery},{name: aggressive_reset, type: clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery}]"/>
```

I read on line in the wiki docs for 'move_base' that this parameter should exist, but obviously I don't know how to specify it correctly.

This is the link for the move_base docs. http://wiki.ros.org/move_base . Any help...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143426/recovery_behaviors-move_base-turtlebot-amcl/) by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL is not the same as navigation. AMCL is a package to achieve localization and can be run along with (as part of) the navigation stack. Check your recovery_behavior_enabled parameter. And also check the standard output of move_base to see if it states that it is entering recovery behavior.

There isn't enough information in the question. There could be another reason why your robot is not going into recovery other than the param you mentioned above (which is correctly specified BTW)

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0